# Mostrar la fecha mas alta de un conjunto de datos SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

Buen dia,

Quisiera me pudieran apoyar con una consulta, lo que pretendo hacer es poder mostrar la fecha mas alta de determinada transacción, todas las transacciones se guardan en una tabla que se llama Evento_Facial, en esa tabla pueden existir varios registros de la misma transaccion pero con hora diferente y en la consulta que implemente hago un inner join para traerme todos esos resultados, sin embargo el resultado me incluye todas las transacciones de todas las horas que se registro el evento. Como puedo hacer para que en mi consulta solo me muestre la transaccion con la fecha y hora mas reciente? Este es mi consulta y pongo el resultado

DECLARE  @FechaInicial varchar(23) =  '13-09-2023'
,@FechaFinal varchar(23) =  '13-09-2023'

```
DECLARE @Dia  DATE
DECLARE @Dia2 DATE

SET @Dia = CONVERT(DATE, @FechaInicial, 103)
SET @Dia2 = CONVERT(DATE, @FechaFinal, 103)

SELECT * FROM (

select EF_Id as EPRCentralId,
DF.Carril_Id as EPRCarrilId,
CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(EF.[HoraEventoOriginal],',','')) as EPR_Fecha,
DF.Descripcion as Caseta_Nombre,
DF.Carril_Id as Carril_Nombre,
DF.Descripcion as CarrilTipoDireccion_Nombre,
CASE WHEN DF.EstatusDispositivo = 128 THEN 'Activo' WHEN DF.EstatusDispositivo = 1 THEN 'Inactivo' END AS CarrilStatus_Nombre, 
(select distinct TOP 1 P.Persona_Nombre + ' ' + P.Persona_APaterno + ' '+ P.Persona_AMaterno  from PersonaExterna as P where Persona_Externa_Id =  UDFP.Usuario_Id ) as EPR_UsuarioNombre,
EF.TipoAccesso + ' ' + EF.No_Tarjeta as EPR_UsuarioCredencial,
(select distinct TOP 1 P.Persona_Domicilio_Id  from PersonaExterna_Asignacion as P where P.Persona_Externa_Id =  UDFP.Usuario_Id ) as Domicilio_Id,
dbo.ConsultaDomicilioByID((select distinct TOP 1 P.Persona_Domicilio_Id  from PersonaExterna_Asignacion as P where P.Persona_Externa_Id =  UDFP.Usuario_Id )) AS EPR_DomicilioNombre,
EF.Dispositivo_Time as EPR_FechaEnvio,
UDFP.UsuarioTipo_Id as SisUsu_Id
from Eventos_Faciales as EF inner join FC_ListaDispositivosFaciales as DF on EF.Dispositivo_Ip = DF.Ip
inner join FC_UsuarioDispositivosFacialesPermitidos as UDFP on EF.UDFP_Id = UDFP.UDFP_Id
WHERE CAST(EF.Dispositivo_Time AS date) BETWEEN @Dia AND @Dia2 and UDFP.UsuarioTipo_Id = 4

) AS Datos order by Datos.EPR_Fecha desc
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, remarque en color rojo los registros que se "repiten" y lo que quiero hacer es solo traerme el que tenga la fecha mas alta.

Ojala me puedan echar la mano en esta consulta que llevo dos dias y no he logrado resolver.

Estructura de la tabla FC_ListaDispositivosFaciales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura de la tabla FC_UsuarioDispositivosFacialesPermitidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura de la tabla Eventos_Faciales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como les comentaba en esta tabla de Eventos_Faciales se registran todo los eventos de una persona que pone su rostro en un lector facial para permitir el acceso a determinada área. Remarque en color rojo un ejemplo donde el lector por alguna razón lee tres veces a la misma persona, pero esto sucede muy rápido, por lo cual se graba en la tabla Eventos_Faciales esas tres transacciones que hace lectura el lector y lo que quiero hacer es que en la consulta que mostre al principio (para mostrar en un grid) solo me traiga el evento o transaccion con la fecha mas alta. No se si con esto se pueda entender mejor lo que se prentende hacer

Comment: Esta consulta tiene muchos problemas que no sabria ni por donde empezar porque se salen de lo que preguntas. ¿Podrías añadir la estructura de las tablas para hacer pruebas?

Comment: Saludos, ya intentaste investigar sobre la clausula MAX? Puedes revisar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71084663/is-this-possible-in-sql-min-and-max-dates-on-a-total-where-it-changes-in-betwe) una respuesta similar.

Comment: @ErnestoRincon: `max()` no es una cláusula, es una [*función de agregado*](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Gracias por la correccion @Sal . Pero bueno, si solo necesita la fecha mas alta con MAX() deberia bastar.

Comment: @LuisCazares, Muchísimas gracias por responder, claro que si añado la estructura de las tablas involucradas para ver si se puede hacer algo

Comment: @ErnestoRincon, si claro ya utilice la función MAX sin ningun resultado exitoso

Comment: y como es que usaste max, cuando es la solucion a lo que buscas?

Comment: Por favor, pon las salidas _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, tu pregunta corresponde a SQL Server: ponlo en las etiquetas. No olvides además colocar explícitamente cuál es el resultado que se desea obtener. Y lo que estás mostrando no son las estructuras de las tablas, sino los resultados de las consultas que has hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo es parecido al enlace compartido por Ernesto.

SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 IEF.EF_Id FROM Eventos_Faciales IEF INNER JOIN FC_ListaDispositivosFaciales IDF ON IEF.IP = IDF.Ip WHERE IDF.Carril_Id = DF.Carril_Id ORDER BY IEF.HoraEventoOriginal DESC) AS 'ID'
--ef.EF_Id
,DF.Carril_Id
,MAX(EF.HoraEventoOriginal)
FROM Eventos_Faciales EF
INNER JOIN FC_ListaDispositivosFaciales DF
ON EF.IP = DF.Ip
GROUP BY DF.Carril_Id

Saludos,

Comment: No entiendo que es esto.. una respuesta???

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).